# Tensorflow uniform distribution exceeding maximum

Tags: python, tensorflow

Reviewing this snippet of code in tensorflow that should generate uniform data from 0 to 1

```
random_uniform(shape, minval, maxval, dtype, seed, name)

import TensorFlow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

uniform = tf.random_uniform([100],minval=0,maxval=1,dtype=tf.float32)
 sess = tf.Session()

 with tf.Session() as session:
     print uniform.eval()
     plt.hist(uniform.eval(),normed=True)
     plt.show()
```

[image]

It goes beyond 1 on the graph, curious as to why, or it caps at 2?

Comment: What you are showing is a histogram. Values go from 0 to 1, as shown in the X axis. Since `normed=True`, the histogram frequencies (Y axis) are normalized so the total area of the graph adds up to one, hence the Y values.

Comment: OK so the generated values which I believe should be the Y values shouldn't they be from 0 - 1 or is the normalize creating that variation? Also didn't quite get how the area would add to 1, I can see however the X values do move from 0 to 1 and yes histograms can group multiple bars together, that part I understood.

Comment: The Y axis does not represent generated values, but frequencies. The first column is the (normalized) frequency with which values between 0 and 0.1 appear in the data. About graph area, if you take the width of each column (0.1) and multiply by it's height, the total sum is 1.